# admob and android NativeActivity

Tags: android, java-native-interface, admob

I have a very simple question regarding overlaying things such as banner ads over NativeActivity apps. So, where in java I have -

```
public class freddy extends android.app.NativeActivity
```

and then -

```
void android_main(android_app* app) //this in c
```

It seems to me that this - https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#play is not going to work because -

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
layout.addView(adView);
```

is no longer valid. I'm finding very little info on any of this, but it must be catching out a lot of people writing cross-platform apps? Have I missed something obvious? I hope so :)

thanks, tony